# How can you Google search for pages updated recently?

Tags: google-search

I seem to recall years ago Google had a feature where you could search for pages updated "last year", "last month", "last week" etc. Especially when searching through forums, is there's away to filter results that are really old?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [summary of Google search options to limit results by time period](http://jwebnet.net/advancedgooglesearch.html#advDatePeriod) (referenced in second half of [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045239/2269931)),

you can add one of the following **`tbs=qdr`** qualifiers to your Google search query:

```
&tbs=qdr:s [past second]
&tbs=qdr:n [past minute]
&tbs=qdr:h [past hour]
&tbs=qdr:d [past 24 hours (day)]
&tbs=qdr:w [past week]
&tbs=qdr:m [past month]
&tbs=qdr:y [past year]
```

Alternatively, you can use the following for the real-time search option:

```
&tbs=rltm:1 [real time results]
```